# React native - create one common function that can be shared between 2 or more screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function

I have 2 screens, SignUpScreen and CreateCommunityScreen, and these 2 screens have an icon which calls the same function pickImage whenever the icon is clicked.  How do I create one function for both screens?  Here's what I have so far, but I encountered the error "Error: You attempted to set the key `_V` with the value `1` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen."  Thanks in advance.

pickImage function

```
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

const pickImage = async () => {
  let imageURI = "";
  const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

  if (status === "granted") {
    let selectedImage = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!selectedImage.cancelled) {
      imageURI = selectedImage.uri;
    }

    return imageURI;
  }
};

export default pickImage;
```

SignUpScreen

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import AppBrand from "../../component/AppBrand";
import AuthenticationForm from "../../component/AuthenticationForm";
import CustomButtonLink from "../../component/CustomButtonLink";
import DefaultProfileIcon from "../../component/DefaultProfileIcon";
import pickImage from "../../helper/pickImage";

const SignUpScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  return (
    <View>
      <AppBrand />
      <DefaultProfileIcon
        onPress={() => {
          setImage(pickImage);
          console.log(image);
        }}
      />
      <AuthenticationForm
        btnName={"SIGN UP"}
        onNavigate={() => {
          console.log("image", image);
          console.log("Stays on Sign Up");
        }}
      />
      <CustomButtonLink
        custBtnLinkName={"Cancel"}
        style={styles.spacing_Cancel}
        onNavigate={() => {
          navigation.navigate("Sign In");
        }}
      />
      {image && (
        <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  spacing_Cancel: {
    marginTop: 170,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

export default SignUpScreen;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a file where all the common functions are present (eg. Helper.js)
Add the functions in helper file and export it

```
export function getIcon(){
  Console.log("Get icon function called")
    
  }
```

Now import the file where you want to use it in different screens

eg:
import Helper from '..path of the file'

and use it like

```
Helper.getIcon()
```